# Why is unique_ptr operator* not noexcept?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, dereference, noexcept

While implementing a basic std library for my hobby OS I came across this and wondered why:

Both `operator->()` and `T* get()` are marked as noexcept, however `operator*()` is not. According to the reference it should be equivalent to `*get()`, which would allow it to be `noexcept` and looking at some implementations I see no reason why it is not.

Why is `unique_ptr`'s dereferencing operator not marked as `noexcept`?

Comment: I am voting to close this issue because it is an error merely based off trusting [cplusplus](http://cplusplus.com/) and cannot be reproduced on other sources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator*)

> - `typename std::add_lvalue_reference<T>::type operator*() const;`
>     (1) (since C++11)
> - `pointer operator->() const noexcept;` (2)    (since C++11)

And then:

> Exceptions:
>   1) may throw, e.g. if `pointer` defines a throwing `operator*`

Comment: Thanks, I was using cplusplus.com which didn't include information about throwing.

Comment: But why isn't it conditionally `noexcept` either? Almost all of the time, a plain pointer will be used, and in this case `*foo.get()` is `noexcept`, but `*foo` is not. I know it matters little in practice because all of these will be `inline` anyway.

Comment: This precision is not actually in the standard, but I think this is what is intended.

Comment: @ArneVogel - See [LWG Issue 2762](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2762).

Answer (score 8):

Because `operator*` for the `pointer` type of `std::unique_ptr` may throw. The `pointer` type alias is [defined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) as:

> `std::remove_reference<Deleter>::type::pointer` if that type exists,
>   otherwise `T`*. Must satisfy NullablePointer

That may be something other that `T*`, it may be a class type that overloads `operator*`.

Comment: I'm just wondering whether it's a good practice to mark `->` `noexcept` in such case. Technically it is indeed `noexcept`, but actually the throw is delayed to the dereference of the returned object. A simple expression `a->b` *might* throw. It will cause some confusion.

Comment: @liliscent - Yes the expression may throw, but it's not unique_ptr's overload where the exception escapes from. The specifier is appropriate, since the function is non throwing, even if the expression potentially is